# Retrieving Orders With Opensea API Blocks me Through Cloudflare

Tags: javascript, ethereum, opensea

I try to get the ids of all items listed for sale in a collection.
I try to do it with a loop and the the api as explained [in the documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-orders).

The problem is that when I define the contract and the item_id I always get an error  that cloudflare blocked me. The problem persists even when I try from a different device and network. At the same time retrieving general asset information works well with other commands of the api.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem on opensea?

```
const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}};

fetch('https://api.opensea.io/wyvern/v1/orders?asset_contract_address=0xbd3531da5cf5857e7cfaa92426877b022e612cf8&bundled=false&include_bundled=false&include_invalid=false&token_id=3881&limit=20&offset=0&order_by=created_date&order_direction=desc', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | api.opensea.io used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
```

Comment: So you need an api key to get buy / sell orders now it looks like.

Comment: Indeed. You can ask for one. They are relatively fast now

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking it seems to be an opensea issue.

https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js/issues/245
https://twitter.com/apiopensea/status/1461135305193443334

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).